# Log Normal Montecarlo

Tags: python, montecarlo, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to fit a Montecarlo simulation using a log normal distribution and I don't understand why the actual vol (the volatility after the simulation)  is so high, it is suppose to correspond a minimum to the expected volatility.
(the Montecarlo is to simulate a portfolio of 2 assets that are private companies - that's why I chose quarterly).

Actually from this : expected_volatilities = np.array([0.3, 0.4])
Companie 1 has an expected volatilities of 0.3
Companie 2 has an expected volatilities of 0.4
I have this huge actual vol after the MC log normal simulation.
Actual Volatilities: [ 6.15159602 10.7589778 ]

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Here is the Montecarlo function:

```
def monte_carlo_simulation_quarterly(expected_returns, expected_volatilities, correlation_matrix, initial_prices, quarters=4, sim_count=1000):
    asset_count = len(initial_prices)
    
    # Convert volatilities to variances
    expected_variances = expected_volatilities ** 2
    
    cholesky_decomp = np.linalg.cholesky(correlation_matrix)
    final_prices = []
    
    for _ in range(sim_count):
        rand_vals = np.random.normal(0, 1, (quarters, asset_count))
        correlated_rand_vals = np.dot(rand_vals, cholesky_decomp.T)

        # Calculate quarterly returns using variance
        quarterly_returns = np.exp((expected_returns - expected_variances / 2) / quarters + 
                                   (np.sqrt(expected_variances) / np.sqrt(quarters)) * correlated_rand_vals)
        
        price = initial_prices * np.prod(quarterly_returns, axis=0)
        final_prices.append(price)
    
    final_prices = np.array(final_prices)
    avg_final_prices = np.mean(final_prices, axis=0)
    actual_returns = (avg_final_prices / initial_prices) - 1
    
    # Calculate the actual variance and then convert to volatility
    actual_variances = np.var(final_prices, axis=0) / np.mean(final_prices, axis=0) * quarters
    actual_volatilities = np.sqrt(actual_variances)
    
    return actual_returns, actual_volatilities
```

And here is the calling using input randomly chosen

```
expected_returns = np.array([0.1, 0.12])  # Expected Returns for two assets
expected_volatilities = np.array([0.3, 0.4])  # Expected Volatilities for two assets
correlation_matrix = np.array([[1, 0.5], [0.5, 1]])  # Correlation Matrix
initial_prices = np.array([100, 150])  # Initial Prices for two assets

actual_returns, actual_volatilities = monte_carlo_simulation_quarterly(expected_returns, expected_volatilities, correlation_matrix, initial_prices)

print(f"Actual Returns: {actual_returns}")
print(f"Actual Volatilities: {actual_volatilities}")
```